# How to calculate nth term of higher order GENERALIZED Fibonacci sequence using matrix exponentiation in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, matrix-multiplication, fibonacci

I am interested in calculating the nth term of higher order Fibonacci sequence in C++, using matrix exponentiation, while allowing n to be reasonably large (in the range of hundreds).

The sequences I have described are not Fibonacci sequence only but generalizations of it, of which Fibonacci is order 2, in order 3 3 previous terms are used to calculate the next term, i.e. F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) + F(n - 3), this is usually called Tribonacci, order 4 is Tetranacci, and order 5 Pentanacci... I wish to calculate series up to 36nacci.

I know Fibonacci like sequences grow extremely fast, so I used boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp to allow arbitrary length integers in C++, to let the function be able to calculate several hundredth term.

Order here means number of previous terms used to calculate the next term, Fibonacci is order 2, Tribonacci is order 3 and Tetranacci order 4, etc. Also, the series starts with n - 1 zeros and then S[n] == 1 for series S of order n, i.e. order 2 starts with `[0, 1]` and 3 `[0, 0, 1]` and 4 `[0, 0, 0, 1]`, this specification is consistent with Wikipedia and OEIS and the logic of the sequences.

I have found the matrices that could be used to generate terms for orders 2, 3 and 4 online, and I have found the patterns of how the matrices are made, and wrote functions to generate matrices for arbitrary high orders.

```py
import numpy as np

def onacci_matrix(n: int) -> np.ndarray:
    mat = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=np.uint64)
    mat[0, :] = 1
    for i in range(1, n):
        mat[i, i - 1] = 1

    if not n % 2:
        mat = mat.T

    return mat
```

The matrices for the first five orders are:

```
In [336]: onacci_matrix(2)
Out[336]:
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 0]], dtype=uint64)

In [337]: onacci_matrix(3)
Out[337]:
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint64)

In [338]: onacci_matrix(4)
Out[338]:
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint64)

In [339]: onacci_matrix(5)
Out[339]:
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=uint64)

In [340]: onacci_matrix(6)
Out[340]:
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint64)
```

More specifically, using zero-based indexing, the item located at row 0 column 0 of the base matrix raised to ith power is the item with index i + o - 1 of the series of order o.

```py
from typing import List


def onacci_iterative(n: int, o: int) -> List[int]:
    series = []
    stack = [0] * (o - 1) + [1]
    for _ in range(n + 1):
        stack.append(sum(stack))
        series.append(stack.pop(0))

    return series

ONACCI6 = onacci_matrix(6)
```

```
In [342]: np.linalg.matrix_power(ONACCI6, 19)
Out[342]:
array([[233904, 117920,  59448,  29970,  15109,   7617],
       [230064, 115984,  58472,  29478,  14861,   7492],
       [222447, 112144,  56536,  28502,  14369,   7244],
       [207338, 104527,  52696,  26566,  13393,   6752],
       [177368,  89418,  45079,  22726,  11457,   5776],
       [117920,  59448,  29970,  15109,   7617,   3840]], dtype=uint64)

In [343]: onacci_iterative(24, 6)[24]
Out[343]: 233904
```

Because exponentiation is involved, this can be done using exponentiation by squaring and thus done in logarithmic time.

The matrices are stored as flat vectors to get maximum performance, I have written functions to inspect which elements of a and b are needed for each element of a dot b, and calculated the exact index that for the series of order o has the maximum term representable by unsigned integers of a given width:

```py
def matmul_indices(n: int) -> dict:
    indices = {}
    for y in range(n):
        s = y * n
        for x in range(n):
            indices[s + x] = [(s + z, z * n + x) for z in range(n)]

    return indices


def onacci_limits(o: int, lim: int) -> dict:
    limits = []
    lim = 1 << lim
    for i in range(2, o + 1):
        n = 0
        while onacci(n, i)[-1] <= lim:
            n += 1

        limits.append(n - 1)

    return limits
```

So the following is the C++ code I have written so far:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using boost::uint64_t;
using boost::multiprecision::uint128_t;
using boost::multiprecision::uint256_t;
using boost::multiprecision::uint512_t;
using std::array;
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::vector;

constexpr array<int, 35> ONACCI_64 = {
    93, 75, 71, 70, 70,
    71, 72, 73, 74, 75,
    76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
    81, 82, 83, 84, 85,
    86, 87, 88, 89, 90,
    91, 92, 93, 94, 95,
    96, 97, 98, 99, 100
};

constexpr array<int, 35> ONACCI_128 = { 
    186, 148, 139, 136, 135,
    135, 136, 137, 138, 139,
    140, 141, 142, 143, 144,
    145, 146, 147, 148, 149,
    150, 151, 152, 153, 154,
    155, 156, 157, 158, 159,
    160, 161, 162, 163, 164 
};

constexpr array<int, 35> ONACCI_256 = { 
    370, 293, 274, 267, 265,
    264, 264, 265, 266, 267,
    268, 269, 270, 271, 272,
    273, 274, 275, 276, 277,
    278, 279, 280, 281, 282,
    283, 284, 285, 286, 287,
    288, 289, 290, 291, 292 
};

constexpr array<int, 35> ONACCI_512 = { 
    739, 585, 544, 529, 524,
    521, 521, 521, 522, 523,
    524, 525, 526, 527, 528,
    529, 530, 531, 532, 533,
    534, 535, 536, 537, 538,
    539, 540, 541, 542, 543,
    544, 545, 546, 547, 548 
};


uint64_t square_sum(int n) {
    double sq, cu;
    sq = n * n;
    cu = sq * n;
    return uint64_t(floor(cu / 3 + sq / 2 + double(n) / 6 - 0.5));
}


vector<int> ONACCI_MATRIX(16205);

void generate_matrix(int n) {
    uint64_t start;
    start = square_sum(n - 1);
    if (n & 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {
            auto [q, r] = std::div(i, n);
            ONACCI_MATRIX[start + i] = not q or q - r == 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {
            auto [q, r] = std::div(i, n);
            ONACCI_MATRIX[start + i] = not r or r - q == 1;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
vector<T> square_multiply(const vector<T>& a, const vector<T>& b, int n) {
    int square = n * n;
    vector<T> c(square);
    T s;
    for (int y = 0; y < square; y += n) {
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            s = 0;
            for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
                s += a[y + z] * b[x + z * n];
            }
            c[y + x] = s;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

template <typename T>
T onacci_matrix(int n, int o) {
    if (o < 2 or o > 36) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("order must be between 2 and 36");
    }
    if (n < o - 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == o - 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int square = n * n;
    vector<T> base(square), p(square);
    uint64_t start = square_sum(n - 1);
    for (uint64_t i = start; i < start + square; i++) {
        base[i] = ONACCI_MATRIX[i];
        p[i] = ONACCI_MATRIX[i];
    }
    n -= o;
    while (n) {
        if (n & 1) {
            p = square_multiply<T>(base, p, o);
        }
        base = square_multiply<T>(base, base, o);
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return p[0];
 }

int main()
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= 36; i++) {
        generate_matrix(i);
    }
    uint128_t n = onacci_matrix<uint128_t>(139, 4);
    std::cout << n;
}
```

The code is incomplete, I want to use template functions to test the performance of each type, and I want the program to act like a shell, with the user entering the order of the series and the index of the desired term, the index is then used to determine the smallest bit width that is necessary to make sure there is no overflow. The order must be between 2 and 36, and the term at the index cannot be greater than the range of `uint512_t`.

The code doesn't work, it compiles successfully, but it crashes. I compiled using Visual Studio 2022, with C++20 standard, in Debug x64 mode, and I got error message:

`Expression: vector subscript out of range`

[image]

I am a beginner in C++ and I have no idea what caused the bug, or if there are other bugs, or if my code is completely wrong in the first place.

How to fix the code?

---

I have clicked retry already, and the program just crashes again. And that line 1886 is in the vector.h file, my program has only 136 lines.

Comment: You've gone through a great deal of effort to describe index out of range, which is always a bug and should be solved by a debugger. This is true for whatever language you're using. Have you stepped through your program with a debugger?

Comment: It should be the same principle. But anyway, as I am sure you are aware, you are generally required to provide information about what you did to debug your program. The popup to attached to your question suggests you are only 1 click away from being shown the line that causes the crash, yet, judging by your sentence "*I have no idea what caused the bug*", you do not seem to have tried clicking on `Retry`. What is the highlighted line if you do?

Comment: `vector<T> base(square); for (uint64_t i = start; i < start + square; i++) { base[i] = ...; }` This obviously accesses an index out of bounds whenever `start != 0`

Comment: "And that line 1886 is in the vector.h file" -- go up the call stack to find where in *your* code the problem originated (but it is unfortunate that by default we get dumped deep into standard library code, rather than the point of usage)

Comment: Yes, I believe that more than a direct answer to your question, you need to use this bug as an opportunity to learn how to navigate the basic debugging tools provided to you. Most basic functionalities (that I let you google) are *breakpoints*, *watches* (the Visual studio IDE also automatically tracks local variables inside a *Locals* window) and, as @harold mentions, the *call stack*. Speaking of which, if VS happens to be your IDE, you will find all of the above under the menu: *Debug* > *Windows*.

Comment: half of your onacci matrices are transposed... there's no mathematical justification for that. why do you do that?

Comment: You might want to review [ask]. It's not good that I have to scroll down **four** times to find out that your question is about a runtime error. Even your question title fails to mention this. The time you spent to write up a summary of higher order Fibonacci sequences would have been better spent narrowing down your code to a [mre], with the help of some basic debugging tools (either a debugger or diagnostic output to show you: what is going on, which line of your code triggers the error, the value of the index that is out of bounds, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The title asks about a high-level algorithm, but at the end, your actual question is about a segmentation fault, which, I deduce, is localized as a logical error in your code.

A quick replacement of `.operator[](i)` by `.at(i)`, shows that your code goes out-of-bounds at least once in this loop:

```
    vector<T> base(square), p(square);
...
    for (uint64_t i = start; i < start + square; i++) {
        base.at(i) = ONACCI_MATRIX[i];
        p[i] = ONACCI_MATRIX[i];
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ExYxzfhq1

The error has a bit more information than the MSVC assert dialog:

```
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 885568) >= this->size() (which is 19321)
```

For any non-zero value of `start` it seems inevitable that this will happen.

I don't have a fix because I have no idea what you are trying to do.
Perhaps you mean `i < start + n`; I don't know.

IMO, this sounds like the typical logical error when making linear arrays into 2D arrays instead of using a proper 2D array library.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know what the code was really trying to accomplish.

So when piecing it together I accidentally rewrote the stuff. Here's my iterative any-Order fibonacci:

```
namespace ranges = std::ranges;
namespace views  = ranges::views;
using Int   = uint64_t;

template <size_t Order> static constexpr auto onacci_iterative(uint64_t n) {
    std::array<Int, Order> window{};
    window.back() = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (auto val = window.front())
            if (n-- == 0)
                return val;

        auto sum = ranges::fold_left(window, Int{}, std::plus<>{});
        ranges::copy(views::drop(window, 1), window.begin());
        window.back() = sum;
    }

    throw std::logic_error{"unreachable"};
}
```

Here's a simple demo [Live Online](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/400a0c0912746850):

```
 2: [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987]
 3: [1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504, 927, 1705, 3136, 5768]
 4: [1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 15, 29, 56, 108, 208, 401, 773, 1490, 2872, 5536, 10671]
 5: [1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 61, 120, 236, 464, 912, 1793, 3525, 6930, 13624]
 6: [1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 63, 125, 248, 492, 976, 1936, 3840, 7617, 15109]
 7: [1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 127, 253, 504, 1004, 2000, 3984, 7936, 15808]
 8: [1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 255, 509, 1016, 2028, 4048, 8080, 16128]
 9: [1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 511, 1021, 2040, 4076, 8144, 16272]
10: [1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1023, 2045, 4088, 8172, 16336]
```

### Matrix Approach

I won't do all the matrix logic myself, instead using Boost Ublas:

```
using Matrix = boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<Int>;
```

First of all, let's create the exponentation helper like you describe:

```
template <class T> T my_pow(T b, int64_t e) {
    if (e == 1)
        return b;
    if (e % 2 == 1)
        return prod(b, my_pow(b, e - 1));
    T tmp = my_pow(b, e / 2);
    return prod(tmp, tmp);
}
```

Next, we need the `onacci_matrix` generator:

```
Matrix onacci_matrix(Int order) {
    Matrix m(order, order);
    m.assign(boost::numeric::ublas::zero_matrix<Int>(order, order));

    for (Int i = 0; i < order; ++i)
        m(i, 0) = 1;

    for (Int i = 1; i < order; ++i)
        m(i-1, i) = 1;

    return order % 2 ? trans(m) : m;
}
```

To check that everything is correct, I created a benchmark comparison:

```
template <size_t Order> void compare(uint64_t n) {
    auto timed = [](auto f) {
        auto start = now();
        auto r     = f();
        return std::tuple((now() - start), r);
    };

    auto [itime, itval] = timed([n] { return onacci_iterative<Order>(n); });
    auto [mtime, m]     = timed([n] { return my_pow(onacci_matrix(Order), n); });
    auto mval           = m(0, 0);

    fmt::print("order:{} {:<20} {:10L}μs {}\n", Order, fmt::format("iterative({}):", n), itime / 1us, itval);
    fmt::print("order:{} {:<20} {:10L}μs {}\n", Order, fmt::format("matrix^{}:", n), mtime / 1us, mval);
    fmt::print(" -- itval == mval? {}\n", itval == mval);
}
```

And when you run that like

```
compare<6>(19); // the sample from the question
```

It prints

```
order:6 iterative(19):                0μs 233904
order:6 matrix^19:                   11μs 233904
 -- itval == mval? true
```

This obviously matches the value from the question. Note that although at `n=19` the iterative solution is obviously faster, it's possible to check validity even without scaling the integer type:

```
for (Int n = 19; n < 19e9; n *= 10) {
    compare<3>(n);
    compare<4>(n);
    compare<5>(n);
    compare<6>(n);
}
```

These all correctly check out, 36x "itval == mval? true":

```
order:3 iterative(19):                0μs 66012
order:3 matrix^19:                    2μs 66012
 -- itval == mval? true
order:4 iterative(19):                0μs 147312
order:4 matrix^19:                    1μs 147312
 -- itval == mval? true
order:5 iterative(19):                0μs 203513
order:5 matrix^19:                    2μs 203513
 -- itval == mval? true
order:6 iterative(19):                0μs 233904
order:6 matrix^19:                    7μs 233904
// ...
order:3 iterative(1900):              4μs 12869305375559491231
order:3 matrix^1900:                  2μs 12869305375559491231
 -- itval == mval? true
order:4 iterative(1900):             13μs 6881832060256714257
order:4 matrix^1900:                  3μs 6881832060256714257
 -- itval == mval? true
order:5 iterative(1900):             13μs 11498825699531939336
order:5 matrix^1900:                  4μs 11498825699531939336
 -- itval == mval? true
order:6 iterative(1900):             14μs 16271437555610019488
order:6 matrix^1900:                  7μs 16271437555610019488
 -- itval == mval? true
// ...
order:3 iterative(1900000000):  3,176,897μs 7052199387128452865
order:3 matrix^1900000000:            5μs 7052199387128452865
 -- itval == mval? true
order:4 iterative(1900000000):  8,792,814μs 84094515927825409
order:4 matrix^1900000000:            7μs 84094515927825409
 -- itval == mval? true
order:5 iterative(1900000000):  8,793,596μs 4174985315637410720
order:5 matrix^1900000000:           10μs 4174985315637410720
 -- itval == mval? true
order:6 iterative(1900000000):  9,794,345μs 7912436391526238456
order:6 matrix^1900000000:           13μs 7912436391526238456
 -- itval == mval? true
```

### Multiprecision

To get the actually correct values, let's use Boost Multiprecision. Instead of printing the entire values (which will be very large) we print the ₁₀log (basically, the number of digits).

I benchmarked

- Int = uint64_t: (overflows)

  ```
  order:6 iterative(190000):        1,364μs 10log:18.4885
  order:6 matrix^190000:                8μs 10log:18.4885
   -- itval == mval? true

  real    0m0,014s
  ```
- Int = mp::int128_t: (overflows)

  ```
  order:6 iterative(190000):          803μs 10log:38.4783
  order:6 matrix^190000:               47μs 10log:38.4783
   -- itval == mval? true

  real    0m0,011s
  ```
- Int = mp::int1024_t: (still overflows)

  ```
  order:6 iterative(190000):       29,524μs 10log:308.012
  order:6 matrix^190000:              498μs 10log:308.012
   -- itval == mval? true

  real    0m0,121s
  ```

The only types that will likely fit the bill are arbitrary-precision integer types:

- Int = mp::cpp_int: (never overflows, no link dependency)

  ```
  order:6 iterative(190000):    1,247,917μs 10log:56515.3
  order:6 matrix^190000:          198,435μs 10log:56515.3
   -- itval == mval? true

  real    0m4,039s
  ```
- Int = mp::mpz_int: (can never overflow, uses GMP/MPFR)

  ```
  order:6 iterative(190000):    1,339,042μs 10log:56515.3
  order:6 matrix^190000:           81,846μs 10log:56515.3
   -- itval == mval? true

  real    0m4,057s
  ```

Here's the code with the `mpz_int` enabled: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/907d12676fd7c095)**

```
#define NDEBUG
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
static constexpr auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;

namespace ranges = std::ranges;
namespace views  = ranges::views;

template <size_t Order, typename Int> static constexpr auto onacci_iterative(uint64_t n) {
    std::array<Int, Order> window{};
    window.back() = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (Int const& val = window.front())
            if (n-- == 0)
                return val;

        auto sum = ranges::fold_left(window, Int{}, std::plus<>{});
        ranges::copy(views::drop(window, 1), window.begin());
        window.back() = sum;
    }

    throw std::logic_error{"unreachable"};
}

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>

template <class T> T my_pow(T b, int64_t e) {
    if (e == 1)
        return b;
    if (e % 2 == 1)
        return prod(b, my_pow(b, e - 1));
    T tmp = my_pow(b, e / 2);
    return prod(tmp, tmp);
}

// using Int = uint64_t;
// using Int = boost::multiprecision::int128_t;
// using Int = boost::multiprecision::int1024_t;
// using Int = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
using Int    = boost::multiprecision::mpz_int;
using Matrix = boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<Int>;

using Real = boost::multiprecision::mpf_float_50; // just for log10
using boost::multiprecision::log10;

template <> struct fmt::formatter<Int> : fmt::ostream_formatter { };
template <> struct fmt::formatter<Real> : fmt::ostream_formatter { };

Matrix onacci_matrix(size_t order) {
    Matrix m(order, order);
    m.assign(boost::numeric::ublas::zero_matrix<Int>(order, order));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < order; ++i)
        m(i, 0) = 1;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < order; ++i)
        m(i-1, i) = 1;

    return order % 2 ? trans(m) : m;
}

template <size_t Order> void compare(uint64_t n) {
    auto timed = [](auto f) {
        auto start = now();
        auto r     = f();
        return std::tuple((now() - start), r);
    };

    auto [itime, itval] = timed([n] { return onacci_iterative<Order, Int>(n); });
    auto [mtime, m]     = timed([n] { return my_pow(onacci_matrix(Order), n); });
    auto mval           = m(0, 0);

    fmt::print("order:{} {:<20} {:10L}μs 10log:{}\n", Order, fmt::format("iterative({}):", n), itime / 1us, log10(Real(itval)));
    fmt::print("order:{} {:<20} {:10L}μs 10log:{}\n", Order, fmt::format("matrix^{}:", n), mtime / 1us, log10(Real(mval)));
    fmt::print(" -- itval == mval? {}\n", itval == mval);
}

int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

    for (uint64_t n = 19; n < 19e5; n *= 10) {
        compare<3>(n);
        compare<4>(n);
        compare<5>(n);
        compare<6>(n);
    }
}
```

### SUMMARY

So while nothing above addresses your code, it may help you validating your intermediates, and perhaps getting ballpark measures on what performance to expect.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem shortly after the comments were posted, but I didn't post an answer as it was very late (4 in the morning in China Standard Time), so I went to sleep.

Anyway the problem was caused by simple logic errors in the `onacci_matrix` function.

I tried to click that "Local Windows Debugger" button as hinted by the comments, the same error window pops up when I try to run the program, but if I click "Retry" button I can debug it whereas previously the program just quits.

[image]

So at the lower right corner there is the call stack list that lists all active commands, the commands were listed in reverse chronological order with the latest active command at the top, and if I click the line I will be redirected to where the command originated.

In the mid lower section the "Autos" pane lists all the variables in the stack related to the command.

So the `_Pos` variable has a value of 885568 which is way too high, much higher than the length of `ONACCI_MATRIX` which has a length of 16205.

[image]

There are multiple errors here, as you can see `ONACCI_MATRIX` has a length of 16205 but `base` and `p` both have a size of 19321 which is much greater than the size of the `ONACCI_MATRIX`. They both should be much smaller, and in fact they both should have a size of 16.

The error is caused by this line: `int square = n * n;`, actually it should be `int square = o * o;`, `o` means order of the sequence, so the variable name is completely non-descriptive and I failed to catch the bug immediately.

Now the `start` value is too high, it is 885568 when it should be exactly 13.

It is caused by this line `uint64_t start = square_sum(n - 1);` when it should be `uint64_t start = square_sum(o - 1);`.

Let me explain, I stored all the base matrices of the orders as flat vectors and joined them tail to head, i.e. all the matrices are stored as sections of a single flat vector to make the memory access continuous and thus increase performance.

The first order of the Fibonacci like sequences is 2, as every term is the sum of the previous two terms, and the matrix for it has a length of 4. It is stored at the start of the vector with its first element having an index of 0 and the last 3. Then Tribonacci sequence in which every term is sum of the previous 3 terms, the matrix for it has length of 9, and it is stored immediately after the Fibonacci matrix, it starts at 4 and ends at 12.

Then the Tetranacci sequence, which is what this demo uses, the index starts at 13 and ends at 28.

I did this to make memory access continuous and to get rid of if statements.

Then the following code block caused the index error:

```
    for (uint64_t i = start; i < start + square; i++) {
        base[i] = ONACCI_MATRIX[i];
        p[i] = ONACCI_MATRIX[i];
    }
```

`base` and `p` should both be 16 element vectors here, and `start` should be the sum of all mentioned squares before the current order, here it should be 0+4+9 = 13, I used simple algebra to get rid of iteration and calculate the value in constant time.

But here I wrongly used `n` instead of `o` so the `start` is 885568 which is 0+4+9+16...+19044 which is completely wrong.

The idea here is to get the sequence of `o * o` elements starting at the index `start` of `ONACCI_MATRIX`. Because the elements are shifted by the joining we need to shift it back so that the index `i` in `base` corresponds to index `start + i` in `ONACCI_MATRIX`.

In Python syntax I want `base = ONACCI_MATRIX[start:start+square]; p = base.copy()`, but I messed up the code so that it will always cause index error.

I fixed it to this:

```
    uint64_t j;
    uint64_t start = square_sum(o - 1);
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < square; i++) {
        j = start + i;
        base[i] = ONACCI_MATRIX[j];
        p[i] = ONACCI_MATRIX[j];
    }
```

The full fixed code:

```
template <typename T>
T onacci_matrix(int n, int o) {
    if (o < 2 or o > 36) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("order must be between 2 and 36");
    }
    if (n < o - 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == o - 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int square = o * o;
    vector<T> base(square), p(square);
    uint64_t j;
    uint64_t start = square_sum(o - 1);
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < square; i++) {
        j = start + i;
        base[i] = ONACCI_MATRIX[j];
        p[i] = ONACCI_MATRIX[j];
    }
    n -= o;
    while (n) {
        if (n & 1) {
            p = square_multiply<T>(base, p, o);
        }
        base = square_multiply<T>(base, base, o);
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return p[0];
 }
```

And it does produce the correct result:

```
PS C:\Users\Xeni> C:\Users\Xeni\source\repos\Onacci\x64\Debug\Onacci.exe
326749640703845136024974885271096560873
```

Comment: Appreciate you posting your own analysis. +1 I - in the end - understood your attempt at storing all the onacci matrices contiguously, but I'd personally probably never do that (manually). The worst I can see me do is a big `std::pmr::vector` - which comes down to the same but without the complexity!

Comment: I agree with @sehe, there is no point in forcing so much complicated logic to maintain the generated matrices contiguously in memory. It obscures the code, while it should be the responsibility of an allocator to do that in the worst case. Also, I transformed the corrected code to use a proper array library: https://godbolt.org/z/jc7Kodnxx